# RAM Install configuration

Tags: memory, installation

**Q: 1.** If a motherboard has four RAM slots, and you want 16GB of RAM, Is it better to have four 4GB RAM sticks or two 8GB RAM sticks?

**Q: 2.** If you decide to install two RAM sticks in a four slot motherboard, should the RAM sticks be inserted into the two slots next to each other on either edge of the RAM slot area or every other slot?

**Q: 3.** If I have two sticks of 8GB each already installed in a four slot motherboard, can I install an aditional two sticks of RAM of another brand and/or speed as long as it is the same DDR version?

Comment: Hi - it all depends on your motherboard both in terms of slot mapping and amount of memory supported in total...

Comment: This a theory based question how many sticks of memory do you actually have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Q1.** The configuration of 4 x 4GB or 2 x 8 GB sticks doesn't matter much. Using 2 x 8GB gives SLIGHTLY better performance. When running benchmarks the 2 x 8 GB is a bit better than 4 x 4GB setup. By reading other forum posts, the performance difference between 4 x 4 GB and 2 x 8GB is at max, 1% better.

**Q2.** You can refer to your motherboard manual for the best configuration, but if you have two sticks, you usually install them in the same channel. Your board is probably dual channel, so channel A and B. You'll want to put one stick in channel A slot0 and the other in channel A slot1. In this pic, you would put a stick in each orange slot, or a stick in each yellow slot. [image]

**Q3.** It would be ok to install another brand of RAM, but you want the *same latency, timing and voltage* specs. **Your RAM will automatically clock to the slowest speed stick**. If you have three sticks of DDR3 1833 MHz and one stick of 1333 MHz, all of your sticks will operate at 1333 MHz. You will also want to get RAM that runs in a matching channel. Ex: *Dual Channel vs. Quad Channel.* Depending on your board you would want all your sticks to run in *Dual Channel*, or all of them to run in *Quad Channel*.

For more in-depth information, refer to your motherboard manual. It will be able to answer any detailed questions that deal with compatibility.

Comment: citations would be appreciated for Q1

Answer (score 0):

Check the MB documentation. Is listed the configuration and once you follow it you should find the best configuration(best, better). Some of the MB does not support 8gb module. In your case i will go for 4x4gb instead of 2x8gb. Like i said all should comply with MB documentation/requirements.